# Who is Peter Quill/Star-Lord's father?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

In the *Guardians of the Galaxy* Movie, we see Peter Quill (aka Star-Lord) and meet his mother at the start of the movie.

We also find out at the end that:

> Yondu was meant to deliver Peter to his father.

But who was that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it conflicts with our future works policy; http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We don't know.

James Gunn, director of *Guardians of the Galaxy* and *Guardians of the Galaxy 2* [revealed](http://www.empireonline.com/news/story.asp?NID=41888):

> Gunn had a major revelation for fans trying to work out who Peter Quill's father might be. "It’s definitely not the character who it is in the comics, I’ll say that much."

Answer (score 15):

I assume it's going to come up in future GotG/MCU movies, but:

> In the comics, his father is an alien: J'Son the King of the Spartoi Empire. More info on the guy can be found [here](http://marvel.wikia.com/J%27son_(Earth-616)).

As for special information about him:

> The Spartoi are a race of long-lived Human Aliens from the planet Spartax. Apart from their long lives they haven't really exhibited any other super-powers so far - though *this* at least could change in the MCU. In the comics, they are supposed to be a 'cousin race' to the Shiar - who are a bunch of avian descended Humanoids. This *could* mean the Spartoi are supposed to be avian descended as well. However, they have yet to exhibit any bird-like features, as far as I am aware. The 'super-powers' available to J'son of Spartoi (or Jason of Sparta as he is also known) is mostly the awesome fact of being the ruler of an Empire consisting of 100s of worlds.

With all the talk about 'delivering Peter' to him, he sounds like a pretty likely candidate for the movies too.

Additionally, so far in the movies, Magneto Rights aside, we have seen the story-lines maintain (even exacerbate) daddy issues wherever possible, so this identity to fit right into that mould.

Comment: Does he have any superhuman abilities in the comics?  That link doesn't reference any powers, so is he equivalent to a normal human?

Comment: @Keen Had edited to add that as well. :)

Comment: Excellent, so that means either his father is either a different person in the MCU, or he'll have powers/ancestry that are different in the MCU.

Comment: @Keen As for powers/ancestry it's actually a bit strange even from the comics perpective, he was initially supposed to be unenhanced, but as the years have gone by he's gotten a lot of enhanced traits. So maybe the MCU will just choose to actually specify where they come from - instead of the muddleness of the comics. But yeah, here's to hoping for that!

Comment: There's an interesting bit about the MCU parentage in [this article](http://badassdigest.com/2014/08/03/who-is-star-lords-father/): *So who is Star-Lord's dad? Talking to James Gunn at the Guardians of the Galaxy junket he told me only four people know: himself, Kevin Feige, Michael Rooker and Sean Gunn, who played Kraglin, Yondu's number two. If it was J'Son many more people would know, so I'm pretty sure we can definitively rule out Spartax as Quill's secret origin.*

Comment: I would very much like it to be Loki.